# Confidence band for Cox model using R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, cox-regression

I would like to obtain the 95% confidence bands (not the piecewise confidence interval) for the conditional survival function from the Cox model using R. I know there are a lot of package to compute confidence bands for survival model, but not too many for the Cox model. I wonder if anyone would like to share with me the code or the package. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the same thing and came up with the predictCox function from the riskRegression package. You can find the documentation for example [here](https://rdrr.io/github/tagteam/riskRegression/man/confint.predictCox.html).

It's not very clear from the documentation but from reading the code on github ([here](https://github.com/tagteam/riskRegression/blob/e6c40bedde92c396fb082ef0b933930f88673ef9/R/confint.predictCox.R)) it would seem that in order to estimate bands you need to provide the arguments:
`band=TRUE`, `se=TRUE` and `iid=TRUE`

Comment: Thanks. I found the same package. But I am not sure how exactly they calculate the confidence bands.